# How to query a ContentProvider for value that is not null on Android?

Tags: java, android, sql, android-contentprovider

I have a ContentProvider, and I would like to make a query that returns the rows of a table where the values of a specific column is not null. In SQL you can use the `column IS NOT NULL`, but I cannot figure out what is the equivalent statement in case of ContentProviders.

I have tried so far:

1. SQL like syntax.

   ```
   getContentProvider().query(uri,
           null,
           Contract.Table.COLUMN + " is not null",
           null,
           null);
   ```
2. SQL like syntax with selection arguments.

   ```
   getContentProvider().query(uri,
           null,
           Contract.Table.COLUMN + " is not null",
           new String[0],
           null);
   ```
3. Is on equal with real `null` value.

   ```
   getContentProvider().query(uri,
           null,
           Contract.Table.COLUMN + " != ?",
           new String[]{null},
           null);
   ```
4. Is not equal with `"null"` string.

   ```
   getContentProvider().query(uri,
           null,
           Contract.Table.COLUMN + " != ?",
           new String[]{"null"},
           null);
   ```

Thank you!

Comment: Ask whoever wrote the `ContentProvider`. It is up to the author of the `ContentProvider` how the parameters passed to `query()` get interpreted. For a `ContentProvider` that stores its data in SQLite, I would expect your first syntax to have a decent shot at working, but that is not guaranteed.

Comment: and try " is not null", not "is not null", notice the leading space

Comment: @pskink Thanks, it was a typo. I have space in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ContentProvider`s are not standardized. Each of them may interpret query parameters in any given way. (In fact, most content providers only use a few parameters at all.)